# How do I solve this, do I have to continue calculating with rational fractions?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{\sin^2(x)dx}{\sin(x)+2\cos(x)}$$

I tried to use different substitutions such as $t=\cos(x)$, $t=\sin(x)$, $t=\tan(x)$, and after expressing $\sin$ and $\cos$ through $\tan(\frac{x}{2})$, I've got $ \int -4 \frac{t^2dt}{(1+t^2)^2(t^2-t-1)}.$

Rational fractions didn’t work.

Comment: Could we see what you have done with rational fractions? They work in this case, but will become very very messy. So it's probable you made a small mistake, which we could find with some luck.

Comment: Yea, actually i was wrong, rational fractions works, i’ve found them and now the exercise seems much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$(\sin x+2\cos x)(2\cos x-\sin x)=4-5\sin^2x=5\cos^2x-1$$
Therefore
$${\sin^2x\over \sin x+2\cos x} ={\sin^2x(2\cos x-\sin x)\over (\sin x+2\cos x)(2\cos x-\sin x)}\\ =
2{\sin^2x\over 4-5\sin^2x}\cos x-{1-\cos^2x\over 5\cos^2x -1}\sin x$$
Hence substituting $s=\sin x$ and $t=\cos x,$  respectively, gives
$$\int {\sin^2x\over \sin x+2\cos x}\,dx=2\int{s^2\over 4-5s^2}\,ds +\int{1-t^2\over 5t^2-1}\,dt \\
=-{2\over 5}s+{8\over 5}\int {1\over 4-5s^2}\,ds-{1\over 5}t+{4\over 5}\int{1\over 5t^2-1}\,dt $$
The remaining integrals can be evaluated by easy partial fraction decompositions. At the end we have to get back to $x=\arcsin s$ and $x=\arccos t,$ respectively.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to solve it without rational fractions. The denominator can be written as

$$\sin(x)+2\cos(x) = \sqrt 5\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\sin x + \frac{2}{\sqrt 5}\cos x\right) = \sqrt 5 \sin\left(x+\theta\right)$$

where $\sin\theta = \frac{2}{\sqrt 5}$. Now by the change of variable $x+\theta\rightarrow y$ we get

$$\int \frac{\sin^2(x)dx}{\sin(x)+2\cos(x)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 5} \int \frac{\sin^2(x)dy}{\sin y} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt 5} \int \frac{1-\cos\left(2x\right) dy}{\sin y} = \\\frac{1}{2\sqrt 5} \int \frac{1-\cos\left(2y-2\theta\right) dy}{\sin y} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt 5} \int \frac{1-\cos\left(2y\right)\cos\left(2\theta\right) - \sin\left(2y\right)\sin\left(2\theta\right) dy}{\sin y} =\\
 \frac{1}{2\sqrt 5} \left(\int \frac{dy}{\sin y} - \cos\left(2\theta\right)\int \frac{dy}{\sin y} + 2\cos\left(2\theta\right)\int \sin y dy - 2\sin\left(2\theta\right) \int \cos ydy \right)$$

and I believe you can do the rest.

Comment: after the substitution, shouldn't the $\sqrt 5$ be in the denominator ?

Comment: Hmmm, that's actually true, I edited the answer and thank you!

Comment: At the very end the partial fractions will be applied when calculating $$\int ( \sin y)^{-1}\,dy=\int (1-\cos ^2y)^{-1}\sin y\,dy$$ Unless you have another way of dealing with that integral

Comment: Yes it is true if we integrate it that way. But there is the alternative way of writing $\int \frac{1}{\sin y} dy= \int \csc y dy =  \int \csc y \frac{\csc y + \cot y}{\csc y + \cot y} dy  = \int \frac{\csc^2 y + \csc y \cot y}{\csc y + \cot y} dy = -\ln\left( \csc y + \cot y \right)$ cause the numerator is the negative of the derivative of denominator. But all and all I left the last integrals unsolved because they are basic forms with known answers.

Answer (score 0):

After applying the method with rational fractions i’ve got three fractions in the integral and calculated it separately so that’s the answer i got in the end
-1/5Cos(x)-2/5Sin(x)-4/5^2,5ln(|2/5^0,5tg(x/2)-1/5^0,5-1/(2/5^0,5tg(x/2)-1/5^0,5+1)|+constant
I’m sorry for giving the answer in such an awkward form, but i’ve no idea how to write it correctly here

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).